# Java что располагается внутри фигурных скобок

Tags: java, swing

Встретил вот такой интересный участок кода, но ничего не могу про него найти:

```
JPanel contentPane = new JPanel() {             
            BufferedImage [] img = new BufferedImage[] { // вот это поле
                ImageIO.read(new File("image/_1.png")),
                ImageIO.read(new File("image/_2.png"))
            };

            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawImage(img[0],0,0,null);
            }
        };
```

Почему после конструкции new JPanel() внутри фигурных скобок присутствуют переменные? Как это называется?

Comment: Где анонимный метод? Метод paintComponent имеет имя (которое просто перегружается из `JPanel`). А "приём", видимо, называется "инициализация массива при создании" int[] arr= {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

Comment: За что минусы? Человек просто не разобрался в природе анонимных классов, и его смущает, что мы как бы вмешиваемся в уже готовый класс `JPanel` и что-то там добавляем. Пытаясь понять, в чем тут дело, он добросовестно задает вопрос, как может.

Comment: @m.vokhm видимо два человека считают, что вопрос бесполезен, так как ответ на него известен любому, прочитавшему "Java for dummies" или более сложный учебник. Куда интереснее за что четыре плюса.

Comment: Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос и ответил именно на него (см. ниже), то переформулируйте ваш вопрос, чтобы он более адекватно отражал суть того, что привело вас в замешательство.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev У каждого из нас было время, когда мы еще не читали "Java for dummies", и тем не менее хотели в чем-то разобраться. Если человек пытается что-то понять (а не просто контрольную сдать), я считаю, это можно только приветствовать.

Comment: @m.vokhm не у каждого, очень похоже, что автор вопроса учебник читать не пытался.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То, с чем мы здесь имеем дело -- это не анонимные поля, это описание анонимного класса, который является потомком класса `JPanel`. То, что следует за вызовом конструктора `new JPanel()` в фигурных скобках -- это фактически описание нового класса; вы его описываете и сразу же создаете экземпляр этого нового класса и присваиваете его переменной `contentPane` типа `JPanel` (это возможно, поскольку новый клаcc - дочерний по отношению к JPanel), но вы не можете создавать переменные нового типа, поскольку у нового класса нет своего имени.

Как и любой дочерний класс, новый класс (хоть анонимный, хоть нет) может содержать дополнительные поля и методы, может также переопределять методы родительского класса. Как и при описании любого класса, переменные могут быть инициализированы выражениями, которые вычисляются в момент создания экземпляра класса. Выражения могут содержать вызовы методов, эти методы будут вызываться в момент инициализации. Ваш код

```
BufferedImage [] img = new BufferedImage[] { // вот это поле
            ImageIO.read(new File("image/_1.png")),
            ImageIO.read(new File("image/_2.png"))
        };,
```

занимается именно этим -- создается массив из двух элементов (**не анонимный** -- у него есть имя -- `img`!), для каждого из них вызывается метод `read()`, который возвращает значение, которое и присваивается элементу массива.

Анонимный класс отличается от нормального тем, что у него нет имени, а значит, нельзя описать переменную такого класса, а значит, нет честного способа обратиться извне к тем его полям и методам, которые не описаны в родительском классе. Но описанные в нем методы (в том числе переопределенные методы родительского класса) вполне могут к ним обращаться, например, в вашем коде это `g.drawImage(img[0],0,0,null);`.

Так что конструкция вида

```
MyClass myVar = new MyClass() {

   int number = 123;
   String name = new String("Это объект № ");

   @Override
   public String toString() {
     return name + number;
   }  

   public void foolish() {
     System.out.println("Этот метод не может быть вызван");
   }
}
```

равносильна описанию

```
class NewClass extends MyClass {

   int number = 123;
   String name = new String("Это объект № ");

   @Override
   public String toString() {
     return name + number;
   }  

   public void foolish() {
     System.out.println("Этот метод не может быть вызван");
   }
}

NewClass myVar = new NewClass();
```

за исключением того, что в случае обычного класса вы можете вызвать вновь описанный метод

```
myVar.foolish();
```

а в случае анонимного класса вы этого сделать не можете, поскольку переменная `myVar` относится к типу `MyClass`, который такого метода не содержит.

Comment: Обращения к автору вопроса стоит писать под самим вопросом (пока он сам не начнёт переписку под вашим ответом), иначе он не получит уведомления и не узнает о появлении вашего комментария.

Comment: Самый лучший и человеческий ответ, большое спасибо, всё предельно понятно!

Answer (score 1):

Это не поля класса. Просто создаётся массив экземпляров класса `BufferedImage`. Вызов метода `ImageIO.read(new File("image/_1.png"))`, скорее всего, возвращает экземпляр этого класса. Переписал ваш код для наглядности:

```
public class some { 

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        Other[] arrayOfOther = new Other[] {
            new Other(),
            new Other()
        };
    }

}

class Other{}
```

**Update**

Переписал для вас половину swing-a. Надеюсь будет понятней

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel() {             
                BufferedImage [] img = new BufferedImage[] { // вот это поле
                    ImageIO.read(),
                    ImageIO.read()
                };

                protected void paintComponent(String s) {
                    super.paintComponent(s);
                    System.out.println("Я метод класса-наследника. И да, я имею доступ к массиву `img` " + Arrays.toString(img));
                }
            };        

        contentPane.paintComponent("");
    }

}

// "Оригинальный" класс JPanel. Понятия ни имеет о массиве `BufferedImage [] img`
class JPanel {
    protected void paintComponent(String s) {
        System.out.println("Я метод родительского класса. Меня вызвали. Ура");
    }
}

class BufferedImage {
    public String toString() {
        return "Красивая картинка";
    }
}

class ImageIO {
    static BufferedImage read() {
        return new BufferedImage();
    }
}
```

Попробуйте запустить эту программу.

Comment: Либо я неверно объяснил, либо меня недопоняли.  JPanel класс. Внутри него действительно перегружен метод. И внутри него же мы создаем массив img. Как? Мы можем спокойно завести переменную в фигурных скобках, которая, к тому же, будет доступна в методах класса(перегруженный метод использует эту переменную)?

Comment: Если кратко - да. Пример в обновленном ответе